# how to create events through fullcalendar

Tags: javascript

how to create events and store to database using jquery fullcalendar

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the current version of Fullcalendar only supports displaying the events, not adding new events. So, you will have to create your own solution.

From their webpage:

> DISCLAIMER: FullCalendar is great for
>   displaying events, but it isn't a
>   complete solution for event
>   content-management. Beyond dragging an
>   event to a different time/day, you
>   cannot change an event's name or other
>   associated data. It is up to you to
>   add this functionality through
>   FullCalendar's event hooks.

Comment: i got full code with ruby on rails...but i need code in javascript